# Backlight controle is not working

Tags: backlight

i recently updatet my laptop to ubuntu 15.04 and my backlightcontrole is not working with the fn keys i tried a few things but it did not worked out for me.
hp pavilion dv6 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff)
and i put this in the grub file

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor i915.i915_enable_rc6=7 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1"

unfortunaly it does not work
and also i tried to load my backup from the ubuntu 14.04 and it is not working the only thing what happens is that it kicks me back to lock in screen and if i lock back in every window is closed??? but if i put the backup in a different folder it works but not for everything?

i hope someone of you can help me i installed the system 5 times now because i always messed sth up hehe
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

First use ls /sys/class/backlight/ to see which video card is installed. In my case the above command showed intel_backlight. After this I did:

sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf # create 20-intel.conf file`

sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf #open the file

and add the following lines to this file

Section "Device"
            Identifier  "card0"
            Driver      "intel"
            Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
            BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    EndSection

save and exit. Log out and log-in back.